# How are files added to multiple folders implemented in Google Drive sync?

Tags: google-drive, hardlink

I have a large amount of files in Google Drive, which I need to organize by different criteria. I'm planning to use the feature to add the same file to multiple folders (sort of like hard links in a local file system).

However, I'm not sure what will happen to my synced computer. Will it actually make hard links behind the scenes, or will it just duplicate files? I ask because I don't want the duplicates to consume my available drive space. I haven't managed to find official documentation regarding this, either.

I'm on Windows, but info about Mac and Linux would be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a text file and then adding it to many folders, I tested them with `fsutil hardlink list x.txt` in both locations, but it shows no hard links, which means that, indeed, Google Drive **duplicates files in multiple folders**.

Guess I'll need to use selective sync not to run out of space.